# web part title in xsl

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, web-parts

I'm investigating a possible solution where all web parts on my page should be rendered without a chrome, meaning that the default title portion of the web part will be hidden, but the title supplied in the web part properties should be used elsewhere in the web part.

I have found several solutions on how to get the page title but none around how I can crab the web part title and display it using Xsl, would like to return this within the ItemStyle.xsl

I used a method of return the raw xml data for the web part, but by default is the title of the web part not return, and I found no reference other than OuterTemplate.GetTitle() which points to the Title column of a list, to support my solution.

Is this possible?

Comment: If anybody come across this, just add <xsl:param name="FeedTitle" /> to your xsl, make sure that you don't change the Feed properties in the web part properties tab, and it'll always return the web part assigned title.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not accessible through the xsl itself, as the title of the webpart is not part of the xml data coming through. If you really need it, you could show it on the page and use JQuery/Javascript to scrape it off. Otherwise, I might find a different way to provide the name, maybe with a query parameter.